# Buscar duplicados y sustituir

Tags: javascript

resulta que me mandaron un ejercicio, en el cual debo buscar cuales letras se repiten y colocar un caracter especial en tal caso que se repita (<) y otro en tal caso que no (>).

Ejemplo: Ingresan: 'mañana', el programa debe dar por salida : ><><><

Hasta ahora estaba intentando con los bucles for, pero no entiendo porque no funcionann.

```
  for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
{
  for(let j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
  {
    if(arr[i] === arr[j])
    {
      array.push("<")
    }
    else{
      array.push(">")
    }
  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solo se requiere un ciclo y el uso de [string.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/indexOf) para analizar cada letra:

```js
// Texto de entrada
let entrada = 'mañana';
// Texto de salida
let salida = '';

// Recorrer cada caracter en la cadena
for(let i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
    // Obtener caracter actual
    let char = entrada[i];
    // Buscar caracter en posición anterior
    let antes = entrada.indexOf(char);
    // Buscar en posición posterior
    let despues = entrada.indexOf(char, i + 1);
    // Verificar si está repetido
    if(
        (antes >= 0 && antes < i) // El caracter se repite en posiciones anteriores
        || despues > i // El caracter se repite en posiciones posteriores
    ) {
        // El caracter se repite
        salida += '<';
    } else {
        salida += '>';
    }
}

console.log(salida);
```

**Resultado:** `><><><`

**Notas acerca de `indexOf()` y las variables `antes` y `despues`:**

- **Antes:** Si se proporciona solo un parámetro, se busca el caracter desde el inicio de la cadena. Para saber que hay al menos un caracter repetido, el resultado debe ser mayor o igual que cero y menor que la posición del caracter que se está analizando.
- **Después:** Cuando proporcionas el segundo parámetro, la búsqueda inicia a partir de la posición especificada y, en caso de encontrarlo, el resultado debe ser mayor que la posición actual.

Haciéndolo con dos ciclos (como estás intentando):

```js
let entrada = 'mañana';
let salida = '';

// Recorrer toda la cadena
for(let i = 0; i < entrada.length; i++) {
    // Inicializar valor
    let repetido = false;
    // Recorrer desde el inicio hasta el final o se encuentre coincidencia
    for(let j = 0; j < entrada.length; j++) {
        if(
            i != j  // No comparar el mismo caracter o todo saldrá repetido
            && entrada[i] == entrada[j] // Ambos caracteres son iguales
        ) {
            // Ok, está repetido
            repetido = true;
            // Fin del ciclo, no es necesario seguir buscando
            break;
        }
    }
    if(repetido) {
        salida += '<';
    } else {
        salida += '>';
    }
}

console.log(salida);
```

**Notas finales:**

- Si quieres hacerlo con arreglos, el funcionamiento es exactamente el mismo, tanto con `indexOf()` como con ciclos, solo cambia la forma de asignar el valor.
- Separé las comparaciones en varias líneas solo para agregar comentarios; la verdad, se ve muy feo como quedó.

Answer (score 0):

Haciéndolo un poco más simplificado y fácil de entender, es el siguiente ejemplo:

Lo puedes adaptar también con `arrays`.

```js
    var palabra = "mañana";
    var contador = 0;

    for(var i = 0; i < palabra.length; i++){
        for(var j = 0; j < palabra.length; j++){

            if(palabra[i] == palabra[j]){
                
                contador += 1;
            }
            
        }//for2

        if(contador >= 2){

            palabra = palabra.replaceAll(palabra[i], '<');  

        }else if(contador == 1){

            palabra = palabra.replaceAll(palabra[i], '>');
        }

        contador = 0;   

    }//for 1

    
    alert(palabra);
```